# Making a draggable, resizable image on canvas

Tags: html, canvas, draggable

I am reading this tutorial about making draggable and resizable rectangles
http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape

It is a good one and I want to create a similar one using images and this is what I had done
http://jsfiddle.net/LUhsK/2/

all i had done is to change the script that instead of drawing a square I draw an image given the image source, initial X, initial Y, width and height but as you can see it doesn't work. I really can't find what seems to be the problem

Comment: There seems to be a lot of issues with your fiddle.  First you don't need to add an event listener in the fiddle.  You just call your function in the fiddle window. I changed your fiddle to do that and I started running into a bunch of JS errors: addImg not defined, imgsrc not defined, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understood what you are searching for I guess it can be easily resolved with

```
droppedElement = ui.helper.clone();
droppedElement.resizable();
```